# Reload instance var inside rack/rails route constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rack

I've got a custom routing constraint.

```
class TenantConstraints
  def initialize
    @domains = Domain.mapped_domains
  end

  def matches?(request)
    @domains[domain].presence
  end
end
```

Pretty similar to the [IP Blacklist example on the Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints).

I'm wondering though how you would update @domains or @ips (in the docs example case) when the data from that model changes without having to restart the whole server. I considered adding a cache to `mapped_domains` and using that in `matches?` without the instance var. Is there some way to "touch" that instance var? I've got a similar situation in a middleware as well, so I'd love to have a simple solution for both.

Comment: does it really have to be at route layer? rather at a controller layer

Comment: @emaillenin for this question, yes it does

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure, but you can give this a try:

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :reload_routes

  def reload_routes
    YourAppname::Application.routes_reloader.reload!
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting concept, I'll give that a shot locally. Thanks!